# set the correct scope for ng-click inside a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use ng-repeat-start together with ng-repeat in my code. Basically the HTML table structure I am trying to archive is

```
<table ng-controller="orderListController">
<tbody class="table-sections-header" ng-repeat-start="order in orders" ng-controller="orderDetailController">
 <tr>
     <td>
</tbody>
<tbody class="table-childrows" ng-repeat-end>
 <tr ng-repeat="item in order.items">
     <td>
        <button ng-click="delete($index)>Delete</button>
</tbody>
```

If I create the delete function in **orderDetailerController**, it never gets called, however if I create this delete function in the **orderListController**, it gets called.

what i should do to make it call the delete function inside **orderDetailController**?

I put the sample code at http://jsbin.com/mubeyogeqo/edit?html,js,output
If it works right, when you click on "Descricao 1" or "Descricao 2", its URL should be displayed.

Comment: Check out the scope for the ng-controller="orderDetailController" as it is written, it's isolated to the <tbody> it is on, which doesn't include the second <tbody> where your ng-click is.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this problem. Not sure what's the best way to fix it. Any idea?

Comment: You can move your logic to the controller for the table block: orderListController, or create controllers for each tbody.